# Tool for get image sources parsed from css

Tags: css

Task is simple. Have a tool which will parse `CSS` on network website, read the links to images from there and download all of them to structured folders to local disc.

The important is that tool should ready to use, and designer should be able to use. Answer "you can write the tool itself is OK", but not acceptible for ready tool .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get urls from css manually with regular expressions.

Comment: yes thats true, but tool (already done) is what I´m looking for. Lets say GUI tool that styler-man and no only programer, can use.

Comment: How about writing one based on the knowledge you gather from these answers?

Comment: You are true on it. Actualy instead of do self made FTP client I use Filezilla. If there will be no solution to take it and use I will do.

Comment: Marked as answer while looks this tool is not present on market. Inspiration for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To accompany Roman's answer:

```
/\burl\(['"]?([^'"\)]+)['"]?\)\b/g
```

will match as `$1` almost all images (*almost all* meaning, that the central part `['"\)]` is a bit too strict and will not match URLs with either of these characters in it).

Note that you might get external stylesheets ('`@import`'), too, with this regexp.